# Sound Identification--need help identifying mystery gear noise from a 2005 XC90

Tags: noise, volvo, xc90

Recently this `2005 Volvo XC90 2.5T AWD, AW55-50` started to make this burring whine noise as the vehicle shifts into 2nd gear. As the car revs up and ultimately shifts into 2nd the noise occurs with 100% reproduction just as the tachometer crosses over `2k RPMs`. This noise began occurring at `170,762 miles` on the engine. The noise is coming from somewhere in the drivetrain I'm guessing? Maybe the transmission or the gearbox or something? I'm not too sure where its coming from and hope someone can identify the noise for us.

Is this sound an instance of gear whine? I annotate multiple instances in this video I just uploaded to YouTube using green text overlaid on the video: [Volvo XC90 Mystery Sound (gear whine?)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hutzNapGPzw)

I haven't fully identified the source of the sound but I set a few microphones around where I suspect the sound is coming from. This first recording is focused on the transfer case aka bevel gear. One of the microphones (the [contact mic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_microphone)) is clipped on to a rib beneath the transfer case like you see in the photo below, the other (a [lavalier mic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavalier_microphone)) is taped to a cross frame member facing up to the same transfer case (which as you can see is leaking some old greasy dehydrated oil and gunk).

[image: contact mic attached to transfer case]

I'll be checking the bevel gear oil level soon and maybe drain and fill it and also take a few more recordings to zero in on the sound by studying which mic pics up the loudest. As always any help folks can offer will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's your mileage, and has the gearbox/transmission ever been serviced?

Comment: You state the noise starts in 2nd gear at 2k rpm. Does it come back in subsequent gears or does it go away when it shifts to 3rd?

Comment: @GdD no service since I've owned the vehicle other than a transmission fluid drain and fill some years back. The sound started at 170,762 miles, totally forgot to include that detail. I'll edit the post to include that detail thanks for asking.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 doesn't seem to reoccur in higher gears at all from what I've seen. Here's a snippet if you watch this audio block from between [0:32](https://youtu.be/hutzNapGPzw?t=32) and ending at 0:41, shifting into third car be heard at 0:39. I collected more recordings yesterday evening and started to mess around with manual shifting this time to artificially delay shifts and all that. The recording I link in the post is all automatic shifting. I still have to review the new footage I captured, I'll feed back the findings when I do.